# How do I authenticate my own android app to call my RESTApi?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, security, registration

I have a nodeJS RESTApi. I have secured all the endpoints with a token exchange authentication but the POST /register/ endpoint is open which is used by my client application (Android and Ios app) to register a new user on the service.

I understand the need for this endpoint to be open without requiring authentication but how do I prevent abuse of this endpoint by man in the middle?

Is there a way to authenticate that the requests for registration are coming from my android or Ios application (which can be installed by any user worldwide,so no specific IPs)?

Is there any other possible way to actually prevent false registrations than *damage limiting* measures like rate throttling and other such methods?

I am no expert at this and open to any kind of suggestions and experience with such open registration endpoints.
Thank you.